# Expresion regular que coincida con un rango de horas dentro de un string

Tags: regex, mongodb, pcre

Me gustaría saber si es posible, a través de una expresión regular, con un string que contiene la fecha y la hora, saber si la hora está dentro de un rango de dado.

Por ejemplo:

```
2016-10-17T08:44:04.000+0000
```

Me gustaría saber si la hora dentro de ese string se encuentra entre las `08` y las `10`.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje de programación? "*entre las 08 y las 10*", ¿incluye a las `10:59:59`? ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Busca un "parseador" de fechas para tu lenguaje de programación y úsalo para que te de esa cadena transformada a fecha y trabajar con ella más cómodamente.

Comment: Es para añadir a una query contra MongoDB el regex https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 2):

La forma más eficiente de solucionarlo sería grabar la hora por separado, permitiendo indexar por ese campo y obtener resultados más rápidos.

Si aún te interesa hacerlo con una expresión regular, se podría validar el rango de 08 a 10 con la siguiente expresión:

```regex
/T(?:0[89]|10)/
```

En este caso, se comparan los 2 dígitos que vienen después de la `T`, haciendo que coincida con cualquier texto que contenga `T08`, `T09` o `T10`. Es decir que coincide con horas entre las 08:00 y las 10:59.